# Limit array size inside a document of Mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

i have a document like this

```
{
"_id":"deviceId",
"scannedTags":[{tagId:"tagid", "someOtherDetail":"someOtherDetail"}]
}
```

I need to limit `scannedTags` array size to 20.

My situation is slightly different from that of [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636010/limit-multiple-mongodb-array-size) . My total length of the array should not exceed 20. After pushing 20 elements (not in one shot, may be at multiple situations), the 21st element should overwrite the 1st element in the array.

Currently I am retrieving the array, finding the length, if more than 20, using javascript's `unshift` to insert the element at the first index and then making `array.lenght = 20`. then, i update the document in the collection in MongoDB.

There is a lot of IO involved in this.

Another approach could be using a capped collection, setting the collection size to 20 and keeping deviceid as the collection name: the downside is the number of devices is too many, which are going to increase the number collections in db. 
even if i compromise on the number of collections, the query to get the data from these collections will get performance unfriendly.

is there a way with a single push, i can ensure only most recent 20 records exists in the document?

Comment: The accepted answer on the SO question you linked is actually what you are looking for: pushing to a capped array using `$each` and `$slice`. For example, to limit an array to the last 20 items: `db.devices.update({_id: "deviceId"},{$push:{scannedTags:{$each:["someOtherDetail"],$slice:-20}}})`. If that doesn't solve your use case, please edit your question to provide more detail on your use case and the outcome you expect.

Comment: Note: if you want to be extra sure you can also add a [`$jsonSchema` validation rule](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/) in MongoDB 3.6+ specifying the `minItems` and `maxItems` for your `scannedTags` array.  With a ``maxItems:20` rule for `scannedTags`, any inserts or updates with an array of more than 20 items would fail with a document validation exception.